# "Unsafe Javascript attempt to access frame" in Android WebChromeClient WebView

Tags: javascript, android, webview, youtube

I'm implementing a WebView fragment that loads its content from HTML passed by an activity.
Basically the HTML content is just a paragraph and an embebbed youtube video.
In the emulator everything works fine (Nexus 5X API 24) but when I test it in my real device (API 17) the WebView just shows the paragraph and a black box (where the youtube video should be loaded)
The logs shows this error:

```
E/Web Console: Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL about:blank from frame with URL https://www.youtube.com/embed/blablabla. Domains, protocols and ports must match.
```

I even tried to disable all security checks (yes I know that is not a good thing) with this configuration:

```
mWebView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

But the error persists, the strange thing is that in the emulator works perfectly AND I wrote another application that does exactly the same thing with the same code but without fragments, and it works!
What can cause this error? I figured out that is something to do with SOP, but it should not work in any case, but it does.

Comment: Ok I was wrong, even the other app in the real device does not work correctly